# Is this regular expression optimizable (reduced match steps)

Tags: regex, preg-match, pcre

requirement that need to handle:

```
only ascii letters in lower register [a-z], digits [0-9], "/" and "-"
the string should begin with "/"
"/" and "-" should not stand next to each other nor self in ANY combination 
string must end with a ascii letters in lower register [a-z], digits [0-9] and "/"
```

what I have so far:

```
^((?:(?![0-9a-z\/\-]*?(\/|\-)(\/|\-)))\/[0-9a-z\/\-]*?[0-9a-z\/]$)
```

link to debug [regex debugger](http://regex101.com/r/tW3iT8/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your requirements, you can use this pattern:

```
\A/(?>[a-z0-9]+[-/])*[a-z0-9]++/?\z
```